# Editting a string variable in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a bash script which queries a postgresql database (fyi, it is a SOGo groupware database) and gets a string of text into a variable. The value of the variable (let's call it teststr) looks like this:

```
c_defaults ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"SOGoTimeFormat": "%H:%M", "SOGoMailShowSubscribedFoldersOnly": "0", "SOGoMailSignaturePlacement": "below", "SOGoLanguage": "English", "SOGoDayEndTime": "18:00", "SOGoDefaultCalendar": "selected", "SOGoFirstWeekOfYear": "January1", "SOGoFirstDayOfWeek": "0", "SOGoTimeZone": "Asia\/Kolkata", "SOGoContactsCategories": ["Business Partner", "Colleague", "Competitor", "Customer", "Family", "Friend", "Press", "Provider", "VIP"], "Vacation": {"enabled": 0, "endDate": 1374690600, "autoReplyEmailAddresses": ["testuser@testdomain.com"], "ignoreLists": 1, "autoReplyText": "", "daysBetweenResponse": "7", "endDateEnabled": 0}, "SOGoCalendarTasksDefaultClassification": "PUBLIC", "SOGoMailSortByThreads": "0", "SOGoMailMessageCheck": "manually", "SOGoMailMessageForwarding": "inline", "SOGoLoginModule": "Mail", "SOGoCalendarCategoriesColors": {"Customer": "#aaa", "Calls": "#aaa", "Favorites": "#aaa", "Meeting": "#aaa", "Ideas": "#aaa", "Miscellaneous": "#aaa", "Birthday": "#aaa", "Anniversary": "#aaa", "Vacation": "#aaa", "Travel": "#aaa", "Projects": "#aaa", "Suppliers": "#aaa", "Gifts": "#aaa", "Clients": "#aaa", "Issues": "#aaa", "Business": "#aaa", "Holidays": "#aaa", "Personal": "#aaa", "Status": "#aaa", "Public Holiday": "#aaa", "Follow up": "#aaa", "Competition": "#aaa"}, "SOGoBusyOffHours": "0", "SOGoCalendarCategories": ["Customer", "Calls", "Favorites", "Meeting", "Ideas", "Miscellaneous", "Birthday", "Anniversary", "Vacation", "Travel", "Projects", "Suppliers", "Gifts", "Clients", "Issues", "Business", "Holidays", "Personal", "Status", "Competition", "Follow up", "Public Holiday"], "SOGoCalendarEventsDefaultClassification": "PUBLIC", "Forward": {"enabled": 1, "forwardAddress": ["testuser1@testdomain.com", "testuser2@testdomain.com"], "keepCopy": 1}, "SOGoRememberLastModule": "0", "SOGoMailReplyPlacement": "below", "SOGoMailDisplayRemoteInlineImages": "never", "SOGoSieveFilters": [{"actions": [{"method": "fileinto", "argument": "INBOX\/spam"}], "active": 1, "rules": [{"operator": "contains", "field": "subject", "value": "[SPAM]"}], "match": "any", "name": "spam"}, {"actions": [{"method": "fileinto", "argument": "INBOX\/spam"}], "active": 1, "rules": [{"operator": "contains", "field": "subject", "value": "TESTTEST"}], "match": "any", "name": "new"}], "SOGoDayStartTime": "08:00", "SOGoMailComposeMessageType": "text"} (1 row)
```

Now, what I want to do is remove all the data from the beginning all the way until the opening curly brace(i.e remove c_defaults and all the dashes and one space just before the beginning of the curly brace) and remove the data at the end after the closing curly brace (i.e. the whitespace and the *'(1 row)'* string).

At the end, the teststr string should only have the values inside the curly braces. Is there any sort of regex/awking that can be done to edit this string?

**Edit**

I tried the following steps:
Wrote the variable called teststr into a file. ***catted*** and ***awked*** the file from $3 to $187 (for this example) into another file and read that into a variable. But the size isn't always going to remain the same as values inside the curly braces will surely increase as the user saves more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` to remove anything up to the first `{` and everything after `}`:

```
sed -e 's/^[^{]*//g' -e 's/}[^}]*$/}/' file
```

Comment: This worked. I am quickly reading up on **sed and regular expressions** to clearly understand what is happening here (I am only familiar with the bare basics of sed and have never combined it with regular expressions). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to do an in-place edit. (`-i` option). This can be called from bash.

```
sed -i -e 's/c_defaults\s[-\s]+//g' filename
```

Use `Perl` to do an in-place edit. (`-i` option). Invoked by bash.

```
> perl -pi -e 's/c_defaults\s[-\s]+//g' filename
```

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation? I am not familiar with perl.

Answer (score 0):

You could just match the container with sed:

```
sed -ne '/{.*}/{ s|^[^{]*\({.*}\)[^}]*$|\1|; p; }' file
```

If you get data from a command you could just pipe it:

```
your_command a b | sed -ne '/{.*}/{ s|^[^{]*\({.*}\)[^}]*$|\1|; p; }'
```

And save it to a variable:

```
VAR=$(your_command a b | sed -ne '/{.*}/{ s|^[^{]*\({.*}\)[^}]*$|\1|; p; }')
```

Comment: Careful, `sed` is greedy so your `s|.*\({.*}\).*|\1|;` will get less than you hope.

Comment: @cnicutar I considered `s|^[^{]*\({.*}\)[^}]*$|\1|` but I find the smaller one enough and I had already tested it.

Comment: Perhaps we're using different versions of sed then, because I also tested it and it captures a smaller portion of a text (i.e. an inner {...}). I am using `GNU sed version 4.2.1`, how about you ?

Comment: @cnicutar 4.2.1 here as well. Seems like your correct. I only looked at the end. Sorry for that.